# Is there any way to change the underlying MPDF configuration options using niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf

Tags: laravel, pdf

We're using niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf. Is there any way we can set the MPDF configuration options as documented in [Here](https://mpdf.github.io/). Obviously we could drop into the vendor code section, but causes issues in regards to code maintenance.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For sure do not change anything in vendor.

As the documentation states...

You can redefine the variables in individual scripts as a [configuration variable](https://mpdf.github.io/configuration/configuration-v7-x.html).

You can store this config in a variable in your `config/app.php` for example and then reuse it in all your mpdf scripts.